# Running JUnit + Eclipse, almost always hangs on the last test

Tags: eclipse, junit

I've been studying very simple unit tests, but my last test almost always hangs, for no apparent reason. I was using JUnit 3 + Java 6u20 on Eclipse 3.6 build 20110301-1815, tried updating Java to 6u26 and JUnit to version 4. Also checked for updates on Eclipse. It didn't matter.

The code in the test is irrelevant too. Right now, it hanged here:

```
public void testAdd() {
    assertEquals(2, 1+1);
    assertEquals(4, 2+2);
    assertEquals(-8, -12+4);
}
```

I have no idea what's causing this behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: If you switch the JUnit view to another and back again does the test suddenly go green?

Comment: It didn't seem to matter. I switched and reran and got it green. Then tried again, it hanged, I switched, reran, and it hanged again.

Comment: Added a testNothing() {}. It hangs.

Comment: at least my Eclipse does not update the JUnit view accordingly so sometimes the view hangs but the tests were successful, so just rearranging the view does help with that. I'm not shure what hangs means for you, does the test thread not finish (even in Console)?

Comment: The console shows it as finished, but the view doesn't acknowledge that. I tried fiddling with the view as you say but it doesn't give me a green bar. If I keep clicking  "Rerun Test" eventually the green bar appears.

Comment: Take a thread dump and analyse what exactly it is getting hung for. VisualVM should help you here.